# How to understand `in the way of writing any tracked files` in `git reset --hard`?

Tags: git, git-reset

In `git-reset`, the `hard` mode:

> --hard
> Resets the index and working tree. Any changes to tracked
> files in the working tree since  are discarded.
> Any untracked files or directories in the way of writing
> any tracked files are simply deleted.

How to understand `Any untracked files or directories in the way of writing any tracked files are simply deleted`?

I did a small experiment:
Create a `dummy` file

```
touch dummy.html
git status -s
```

History as below:

```
b3579f4 (HEAD -> main) Revert "Add a crazzzy experiment"
622be1d Add a crazzzy experiment
```

`git reset --hard 622be1d`, the `dummy` file is intact.

```
➜  my-git-repo git:(main) ✗ git reset --hard 622be1d
HEAD is now at 622be1d Add a crazzzy experiment
➜  my-git-repo git:(main) ✗ git status -s
?? dummy.html
```

`git reset --hard b3579f4`, the `dummy` file is untouched.

```
➜  my-git-repo git:(main) ✗ git reset --hard b3579f4
HEAD is now at b3579f4 Revert "Add a crazzzy experiment"
➜  my-git-repo git:(main) ✗ git status -s
?? dummy.html
```

It looks like that `--hard` mode has no effect on the untracked file. So what's the meaning of `in the way of writing any tracked files`? How to simulate this kind of situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a case in which `git reset --hard` has effects on untracked files.

```
touch a.txt
git add .
git commit -m'init'

echo hello >> a.txt
git add .
git commit -m'hello'

git rm a.txt
echo world > a.txt
git status -s
```

The status output is

```
D  a.txt
?? a.txt
```

The `a.txt` in the index is removed and the one in the work tree is untracked.

```
cat a.txt
world
```

Reset in the mode of `--hard`,

```
git reset --hard
cat a.txt
hello

git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

The untracked `a.txt` in the work tree is deleted. But we could also say it's been overwritten with the tracked `a.txt` in `HEAD`.

Comment: Great demonstration! This case is what I want. Didn't understand `in the way of`' s meaning but now I figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with the definition of a *tracked file*, which is remarkably simple: **A tracked file is a file that is in Git's index.**  Such a file has a name, e.g., `path/to/file.ext`.  Note that there is no such thing as a *directory* or *folder* here, it's just a long name with forward slashes—*always* forward slashes even if the host OS (Windows) is going to call this `path\to\file.ext`.

The simple answer, then, lies in observing that Git is going to write `path/to/file.ext` out to your working tree because `path/to/file.ext` is in Git's index and `git reset --hard` therefore needs to write `path\to\file.ext` (Windows) or `path/to/file.ext` (other OSes).  In order to do this, `path` must be a directory (AKA folder), and `path/to` or `path\to`—whichever will be used—must also be a folder.

So, if there's an existing *file* named `path` or `path/to`, Git will *remove this file* (there's only one, because these OSes say that some path name identifies *either* a file *or* a folder—or, at least on Unix-like systems, special items like fifos and devices and sockets, but either way it's *in the way*).  And that's the simple answer to the question about what the phrase you quoted means.

#### But wait, there's more

There's an issue here.  Git's *index* is separate from Git's *commits*, and `git reset` with `--mixed` or `--hard` is going to *fill in* Git's index *from* the commit you pick:

```
git reset --mixed a123456
```

tells Git to look up commit `a123456` (by hash ID in this case; you could equally say `git reset --mixed origin/zorg` to use remote-tracking name `origin/zorg` to find the hash ID first).

Having found commit `a123456` (or whatever hash ID you've specified), Git must now:

- remove, from its index, any files that *aren't* in `a123456`;
- add, to its index, any files that *are* in `a123456`.

These "remove" and "add" steps *may* involve touching the working tree.

If we use `git reset --soft`, we tell Git *don't touch index or working tree at all*, so that only the first step, moving the branch whose name is stored in `HEAD`, occurs.  If we use `git reset --mixed`, we tell Git *don't touch the working tree at all*, so that only the branch-move and index-resetting occur.  But when we use `--hard`, the working tree must be updated.

The "remove a file from the index" part of this update will *also* remove the corresponding file from the working tree.

To observe this happening, start by creating a file in the working tree, leaving it *untracked* as you did:

```
echo data > some-file
```

Running `git status` will show it as untracked (`?? some-file` in `git status -s` output, for instance).  As you already saw, `git reset --hard` won't change this.

Now *copy the file into Git's index* using:

```
git add some-file
```

Now `git status` will show this as a new file to be committed.  It's not in the *current* (`HEAD`) commit, so the diff from `HEAD` commit to index / staging-area shows `some-file` as new.  It is in both Git's index and your working tree, so the diff from index to working-tree shows nothing.

Now run:

```
git reset --hard
```

which resets to the *current commit*.  This makes Git rip the file `some-file` out of its index, because a file named `some-file` is in Git's index *right now*, but it is not in the (newly-chosen) `HEAD` commit (which "accidentally on purpose" "just happens" to be the same as the previous `HEAD` commit, since we didn't pick some *other* commit to move to).  And we used `--hard` while we did this, so that made Git remove *both files*.

Now repeat the exercise, but use `git reset --mixed` first, *then* `git reset --hard`.  Try to predict the effect.

Finally, repeat the exercise, but before `git reset --hard`, run `git rm --cached some-file`.

See also [ElpieKay's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73753749/1256452) of a file that is in the current commit, is not in Git's index at the moment, and is untracked in the working tree.  I forgot to cover this case above, but it falls out of the same complications.

Comment: Can't express my gratitude in words. Thank you very much for your elaborate explanation...